# How rare is synesthesia?

Tags: perception, synesthesia

I visited a neuropsychologist recently who told me I have Synesthesia. I never really knew what it was, but it's fascinating and I can't believe it isn't the norm among people. For me, certain numbers just have had personalities.

For some reason, the more difficulty I had with the number, the more complex personality it had. For instance, I had a lot of trouble with odd numbers, and larger numbers. Therefore, 1 and 2 do not have personalities. On the contrary, 7 and 9 are the most developed personalities.

How rare is this condition?

Comment: Mia, I took out the part asking for personal stories, as that makes the question "not constructive" by Stack Exchange standards.  However, feel free to fill that in with more scientifically-based questions about the topic.

Comment: I feel like more initial research could be done on this question.  Start by googling synesthesia demographics.  I think there's more than one kind of  synesthete too (upper vs lower)

Comment: Thanks, I have researched it but the results have been varied. I get different answers for each site I get.

Comment: V.S. Ramachandran has studied this syndrome intensively http://www.edge.org/3rd_culture/ramachandran07/ramachandran07_index.html http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Synesthesia#Genetics_of_synesthesia

Comment: Hauser - thanks so much, those articles are very well written. Going to save them. :D

Comment: there was a really good episode on public television about this, looks like it is well documented also!

Comment: It's not really clear how rare it is, because so many people probably have it without knowing that it's a condition. So the population may vary from 1 in 200 to 1 in 200000. Nobody knows how many exactly.

Comment: I think its really common considering myself and most of my family members and friends have it. (Maybe because they are all musicians/ artists?) Its not much of a deal- its when you associate certain words and sounds with a colour. You don't see a colour, you know it is. For example when I hear Billie Eilish' song 'Lovely' I imagine it as mustard yellow and pale blue. I also associate words and number to colours.
For example:
8- indigo purple Wednesday- brown
A- red
limited -yellow/orange
0- black
Janruary - duck egg blue

Comment: this reminds me of the Indian mathematician Ramanujan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Hubbard & Ramachandran (2005):

> [...] the estimated prevalence of synesthesia has varied dramatically, between as many as 1 in 20 (Galton, 1883) and as few as 1 in 25,000 (Cytowic, 1989). The most widely cited study to date suggests that synesthesia occurs in at least 1 in 2000 people (Baron-Cohen et al., 1996), although this is now generally regarded as an underestimate. Our own informal samples have suggested that the prevalence of grapheme-color synesthesia might be between 1 in 200 (Ramachandran and Hubbard, 2001b) and 1 in 100 (Mulvenna et al., 2004). **Subsequent large-scale studies have suggested that the prevalence of synesthesia might be as high as 1 in 20 across all forms and 1 in 100 for grapheme-color synesthesia** (J. Simner, personal communication). This high prevalence argues against the notion that synesthesia is merely a “benign cognitive variant” (see Ward and Mattingley, 2005) and instead suggests that it is a widespread phenomenon that may provide novel insights into the neural basis of the mind (Ramachandran and Hubbard, 2001b).

**References**

> Hubbard, E. M., & Ramachandran, V. S. (2005). Neurocognitive mechanisms of synesthesia. Neuron, 48(3), 509.

Answer (score 6):

The wikipedia Article on [Synesthesia cites some prevalence studies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia#Prevalence_and_genetic_basis)

> Random population studies ...
>   determined that 1 in 23 individuals have some kind of synesthesia,
>   while 1 in 90 have colored graphemes (Simmer et al 2006). Colored days of the week and
>   colored graphemes are the most common types(Simmer et al 2006; Campen, 1999).

#### References

- Simner J, Mulvenna C, Sagiv N, et al. (2006). "Synaesthesia: the prevalence of atypical cross-modal experiences". Perception 35 (8): 1024–33. doi:10.1068/p5469. PMID 17076063.
- Campen C (1999). "Artistic and psychological experiments with synesthesia". Leonardo 32 (1): 9–14. doi:10.1162/002409499552948.